# PostgreSQL: Audio stream storage: bytea vs Large Object

Tags: postgresql, audio

My current application needs to store 3~10MB audio inside PostgreSQL. 
Supported operations include:

- Upload as a whole
- Stream-style random read

It seems that I can either store it as a bytea BLOB or upload it as a large object.

bytea pros:

- Simpler
- ORM/dump-friendly

cons:

- Must access as a whole or use the tricky `substring`
- have to configure my ORM to exclude it from auto fetch

Large Object pros:

- Native random access API without substring()/thin-provision

cons:

- Have to manage OID manually
- Bad modularity: dumping database would output all LOs in it

Which is the best choice?

Comment: the best choice here is keeping files in some storage, architected for this, like s3 or other and keeping in database link for it... large objects and bytea are both great. especially for limited amount of data. but if you expect to grow to at least hundred GB in audio files, I would go to external storage - so it all depends on your plans

Comment: @VaoTsun I agree. However, these audios have to be kept secret so we cannot utilize external cloud services.

Comment: use internal?.. anyway your question is based on opinion - you know cons and pros - choose what is more important